# How to access a view once you have generated it with GII (via YII)?

Tags: yii, gii

I've managed to create several forms using YII and GII, but I'll be honest, I don't understand it perfectly. If anyone can explain this to me, I'd really appreciate it.

Basically, I create accessed the form creator here:

```
index.php/gii/form
```

I then filled in:

```
Model Class: Product
View Name: createProduct
View Path: application.views (default)
Scenario: createProduct
```

When I generate the code, I end up with a file called "createProduct.php" located at:

```
protected\views\createProduct.php
```

1. How do I access this view? I figured something like this should work: http://mysite.com/createProduct (but it doesn't)
2. What do I do if I want to change the link to be: http://mysite.com/admin/products/createProduct

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Gii tells you to modify your controller. It shows the code you should insert after generating process. When you do this you'll be able to access your form by http://yoursite.com/controller/action
2. You can manage your urls using UrlManager. Look this article in docs - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, but the bottom line is, I had to read a lot more for it to make sense to me. Now i get it. Thanks.